# More efficient way to change colours

Tags: c#

I'm learning c# and making a program, which returns some numbers.
In this screenshot, I have the current output.

[image]
I want all of the lines to be formatted like the first, and I can do this, but to me it seems like it could be done more compactly. My code for the output so far is as following:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Out.Write ("coords = ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToString (coords.x) + ", " + Convert.ToString (coords.y));
Console.Out.WriteLine ("coord2 = " + Convert.ToString (coords2.x) + ", " + Convert.ToString (coords2.y));
Console.Out.WriteLine ("distance = " + Convert.ToString (Vector2.getDist (coords, coords2)));
```

And i was wondering basically if there's a way to change the `ForegroundColour` multiple times in the `WriteLine`.

Comment: Just create a little function that takes the property name and the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple method for that:

```
private static void PrintColored<T>(string caption, params T[] values)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.Write(caption + " = ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", values));
}
```

Usage:

```
PrintColored("a", "b", "c");
PrintColored("coords", 1, 2);
```

Output:

```
a = b, c
coords = 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a function which turns an input such as "abc&6def" into "abc" in white then when it gets to &6 it would change the colour to gold then carry on to display the "def".